# @superset-ui/embedded-sdk | embedding dashboard returns 403 forbidden

Tags: apache-superset

Added `@superset-ui/embedded-sdk` according to the instructions https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk to a React App.

Before passing the guest the correct token I get a `401 permissions error` which is expected.

I create a guest token with guest token API as mentioned in  https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/

With this token, I get a `403 forbidden error`. I am not quite able to figure out source of this error.

I have added -
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CORS Options -
'origins': ['http://localhost:3000', '']

What could be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the following flag in `superset_config.py`, worked for me.

```
GUEST_ROLE_NAME = "Gamma"
```

Pls refer https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/22258

Answer (score 0):

If you have added anything in the `allowed domains` section, then try removing it.

Also, public role must have these permissions:

- can read on Chart
- can read on Dataset
- can read on Dashboard
- can read on Database
- can dashboard on Superset
- can explore json on Superset
- all database access on all_database_access

Without these permissions, I was not able to embed the dashboard into my frontend application!

You can add these permissions in the `list role` option in the hamburger menu.

Reference:

- https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/18814#discussioncomment-4056030
- https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/22258
- https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/embedding-superset